# function is reported as undefined within onload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm debugging this problem in Firefox.

Below code reports error on line within onload event, saying that "foo" is not defined.

This is not true because it is indeed defined in utils.js

What I also noticed is that utils.js does appear inside Firefox list of loaded libraries:

[image]

however I can see that utils.js loads fine:

[image]

However it is accessible via direct URL reference and path to script 100% is not a problem

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="util-js" src='js/util.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function() {
    
    foo("test");
}
```

Comment: See the Network inspector in the dev tools. `js/util.js` isn’t the correct path. Which path do you expect and which path is the browser trying to fetch?

Comment: If you post your file/folder structure, we can help double check. You may be missing a `src='./js/util.js` or something simple.

Comment: Is foo is defined inside an IIFE or any other function?. if the path of the script is correct it could be a scope issue. to access function foo in profile.php as described in the question it should be in global scope.

Comment: So... from the directory your HTML page is in you have a `js` folder with `util.js` within the `js` folder? If not, your path is wrong.

Comment: Where is `js/util.js`? It's not in your screenshot.

Comment: The file loads totally fine, I can see this in the Network inspector (thank you @SebastianSimon for the hint)! I could provide screenshot to prove that but I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: What's the content of `utils.js` Maybe function declaration is within enclosed scope?

Comment: No it is defined in global scope - there is nothing odd about it

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out there was another syntax error in utils.js.

Somehow I didn't notice it.

What is more odd execution of code did not break on that error and when code in my other file called "foo" it was undefined.

It appears to me that javascript files are executed independently at least to a certain extent and syntax errors in one file don't break execution in others.